# Deleting a file/s within a folder that hasn't been modified in x seconds, continuously

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, directory, delete-file

I have a folder that contains text files that are constantly updated. I'd like to delete the files that are older than x amount of seconds, which I'm able to do via the following:

```
import os, time, sys
now = time.time()


def file_del(file1):
    try:
        if os.stat(os.path.join(path,file1)).st_mtime < now - 10:
            os.remove(os.path.join(path,file1))
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print(e)
        pass

path = "C:/Users/Username/Folder/"
x = os.listdir(path)

while True:
    for a in x:
        file_del(a)
```

The example above deletes files that are older than 10 seconds. This works if I run the script on the existing files, but does not action new files added to the directory whilst the script is running.

I'd like it to constantly delete files that are placed in the directory if they're unmodified after x seconds.

I'm sure this is possible, I just think there may be a loop missing?

Any help/further clarification is appreciated,

***EDIT FOR ANSWER***

```
    x = os.listdir(path)
    for a in x:
        now = time.time()
        file_del(a)
```

I didn't have the now variable within the loop, so each iteration used the same timestamp to delete the files. All working as expected now.

Comment: `for a in os.listdir(path)` ? You operate all the time on the same list `x` that you took ages ago

Comment: may have to reopen it to update it ?

Comment: Try moving `x = os.listdir(path)` to within the `while True:` loop

Comment: IMO bash/shell commands are better to this thing;

Comment: btw You should also do a `sleep()` so that you don't take 100% of a single core.

Comment: Also, `now = time.time()` will need to be moved inside your `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised my error:

The modified time was captured when the function was called for the first time, it needed to be run every time. I added the now variable to within the while True loop and all working as expected:

```
while True:
    x = os.listdir(path)
    for a in x:
        now = time.time()
        file_del(a)
```

Thanks for the assistance, please suggest if question should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to continue refresh the variable holding the list of files. Copy your file index variable inside the while statement after deletion operation:

```
import os, time, sys
now = time.time()


 def file_del(file1):
    try:
        if os.stat(os.path.join(path,file1)).st_mtime < now - 10:
            os.remove(os.path.join(path,file1))
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print(e)
        pass

path = "C:/Users/Username/Folder/"

x = os.listdir(path)

while True:
    for a in x:
        file_del(a)
        x = os.listdir(path)
```